# How can I use mass assignment together with two model?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have a user model (User). I also have a profile model for this user (Profile).

What I want to do; Batch transferring data from an only form to these two models in the `ProfileController@update` method. But I could not fully grasp this issue. And what's the best practice to do this? I do not know if there is any article I haven't looked at... If you can explain it to me with an example, I would be very happy.

Thank you very much in advance

Here are some codes:

**ProfileController@update**

```php
    public function update(UpdateUserRequest $request, \App\Models\Profile $profile)
    {
        $request->authorize('update', $request->profile);

        // Get all data
        $data = $request->except(['_token', '_method', 'password_confirmation']);

        if($data['password'] == null) {
            unset($data['password']);
        }

        $profile->user($data);
        $profile->update($data);

        toast(__("Profil bilgileriniz başarıyla güncellendi"), 'success');
        return redirect(show_route($profile));
    }
```

**App\Models\Profile.php**

```php
class Profile extends Model
{
    use ImageableModel, ModelStatus;

    protected $fillable = [
        'fullname',
        'experience',
        'birthday',
        'country',
        'status',
        'lang_code',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'birthday' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

**App\Models\User.php**

```php
class User extends Authenticatable implements
    MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'username',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Profile::class, 'id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not doing the following ?

```php
$profile->fullname = $data['fullname'];
$profile->experience = $data['experience'];
$profile->birthday = $data['birthday'];
$profile->country = $data['country'];
$profile->status = $data['status'];
$profile->lang_code = $data['lang_code'];
$profile->save();

$profile->user->username = $data['username'];
$profile->user->email = $data['email'];
$profile->user->save();
```

Comment: Thank you for answer @Franquis. Actually, I like the `$model->update($request->all());` more better. Because it short. :) But, until I find a better solution, I am using the version you wrote.